# @RetryTransaction: how to make it work when deadlock was found

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj

Concurent Transaction make my Sql statements fail.
I'm trying to use [this] dellroad-stuff[1](http://dellroad-stuff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/publish/reports/javadoc/org/dellroad/stuff/spring/RetryTransaction.html). But it seems to be ignored.
I m working with spring 3 and hibernate 4.

The error :

```
15:32:11,331 WARN SqlExceptionHelper:145 - SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
15:32:11,331 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
15:32:11,334 INFO AbstractBatchImpl:195 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

The annoted Function to retry transaction if failed :

```java
@Override   
@RetryTransaction   
@Transactional  
public void save(AnalyseResult analyseResult) {
    final int attempt = RetryTransactionAspect.aspectOf().getAttemptNumber();
    System.out.println("#############");
    System.out.println("Retry Transact : "+attempt);
    System.out.println("#############"); 
    analyseResultDao.save(analyseResult);
}
```

The Beans.xml

```xml
<!--  An @AspectJ aspect will be interpreted as an aspect by Spring AOP and beans
      in the context will be advised accordingly -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="hibernateExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/> 

<bean class="org.dellroad.stuff.spring.RetryTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
     <property name="persistenceExceptionTranslator" ref="hibernateExceptionTranslator"></property>
     <property name="maxRetriesDefault" value="4"></property>
     <property name="initialDelayDefault" value="25"></property>
     <property name="maximumDelayDefault" value="5000"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I reformatted your code and added syntax highlighting so as to make it more readable. But the question is still somewhat unclear. Can you please update the question and show the class containing the `save` method? And please also post your aspect.

Comment: I am also getting a similar error and I am using java config instead, did u find out any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Check you've satisfied all of the following (per the [Javadoc](http://archiecobbs.github.io/dellroad-stuff/site/apidocs/index.html?org/dellroad/stuff/spring/RetryTransaction.html)):

- The method (and/or the containing type) must be annotated with both `@Transactional` and `@RetryTransaction`
- The `@Transactional` annotation must have propagation set to either `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` or `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` (other propagation values do not involve creating new transactions).
- In the case of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` propagation, there must not be a transaction already open in the calling thread (under the same transaction manager). In other words, the invoked method must be the one responsible for creating a new transaction.
- The method's class must be woven (either at build time or runtime) using the AspectJ compiler with the `RetryTransactionAspect` aspect (included in the dellroad-stuff JAR file).
- The `RetryTransactionAspect` aspect must be configured with a `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` appropriate for the ORM layer being used. The simplest way to do this is to include the aspect in your Spring application context, for example:

  ```
  <bean class="org.dellroad.stuff.spring.RetryTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"
  p:persistenceExceptionTranslator-ref="myJpaDialect"/>;
  ```

  This also gives you the opportunity to change the default values for maxRetries(), initialDelay(), and maximumDelay(), which are applied when not explicitly overridden in the annotation, for example:

  ```
   <bean class="org.dellroad.stuff.spring.RetryTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" 
   p:persistenceExceptionTranslator-ref="myJpaDialect" p:maxRetriesDefault="2"
   p:initialDelayDefault="25" p:maximumDelayDefault="5000">;
  ```